# Notificaciones locales con Cordova cada día de la semana a una hora especifica

Tags: javascript, cordova, ng-cordova

Necesito programar una notificación que se repita, por ejemplo, todos los lunes a las 9 am. Encontré este código, pero no funciona,

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Warning',
                    text: 'Im so late',
                    icon: "../img/icon.png",
                    firstAt: monday_9_am,
                    every: "week",
                }).then(function(result) {
                    console.log('Notification 2 triggered');
                });
```

Comment: Puedes probar agregando `date` que es lo que te falta, ejemplo:
`var date = new Date()` `at: date,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código está casi completo excepto en la parte donde le especificas la fecha en el campo `firstAt`

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
    // .....
    firstAt: monday_9_am,
    // .....
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log('Notification 2 triggered');
});
```

Si miras la [documentación](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling) verás que el campo `at` o `firstAt` requiere un tipo de datos `Date o Number` y tu le estas pasando una variable o una cadena (`monday_9_am` no es una cadena, es una variable, `'monday_9_am'` si lo es)

> La fecha y hora cuando el sistema debe mostrar la notificación. Si el valor especificado es `null` o es una fecha en el pasado, la notificación es mostrada inmediatamente.
>
> Default: now ~ new Date()

El truco con este campo es que si quieres que te salga cada lunes a las 9:00 AM tienes que inferir cual es la fecha de tu próximo lunes a las 9:00 AM y programarla para esa fecha, luego el campo `every` se encargará de mostrarla nuevamente con la recurrencia que pusiste a partir de ahí.

Te muestro un ejemplo usando [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), una excelente librería para manipular fechas. Tu eres libre de usar fechas de javascript u otra librería para calcular siempre y cuando le pases al parámetro `firstAt` un objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) o [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) válido.

```
var proximoLunes = moment().set({
        day: 'Monday',
        hour: 9,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        milisecond: 0
    }).add(7, 'days');

$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
    id: 2,
    title: 'Warning',
    text: 'Im so late',
    icon: "../img/icon.png",
    firstAt: proximoLunes.toDate(),
    every: "week",
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log('Notification 2 triggered');
});
```

Comment: pero tengo una duda, como seria para configurar todo un json o un objeto que tenga muchas en diferentes fechas?

Comment: @PedroMiguel Bueno depende de como son tus datos. Se puede usar `$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule([...])` con un arreglo de notificaciones y funciona de manera similar pero recuerda que no es lo mismo multiples notificaciones que una notificacion recurrente. La diferencia se vuelve notable cuando tratas de actualizarlas o [cancelarlas](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/07.-Cancelation). Cuando es recurrente solo actualizas o cancelas una sola, cuando tratas de hacerlo con múltiples notificaciones tienes que actualizar cada una de ellas por separado.

Comment: Entonces que recomiendas, por que la idea era hacer una aplicacion estilo gestion de tareas

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Como dije antes depende de lo que se esta intentando. Al final en tu json puedes especificar si una tarea es recurrente o no, que tipo de recurrencia tiene y programar una notificación simple o recurrente en base a eso. Trata de almacenar una estructura que sea igual o muy aproximada al api de `$cordovaLocalNotification` y listo.

Comment: @Yeisom Gomez No te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar este [repo en Github](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git)

Una vez instalado el plugin puedes accesar a la variable `window.plugin.notification.local`  y escribir lo siguiente:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
date: new Date(),
message: 'Tu notificación'
```

});

Respuesta obtenida de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115844/can-i-schedule-events-callbacks-at-specified-times-each-day-in-phonegap)

Comment: Si, ya la usé, pero solo la ejecuta el día y la fecha dada, necesito es que se repita todos los lunes, y aun no hallo como hacerlo.

Comment: Uhmm y si pruebas con esto, quizá funcione: `repeat:  'monday',`

Comment: Lo probare, muchas gracias :D